# Opening different tab of one page from click in other page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have hyperlink on page A.

On Page B I have two tabs(tabs1 & tab2 content are "display:none").I want when I click A page hyperlink, page B 2nd tab must open/active.

I have am loking for javascript solution.

**APage.html**

```
<a href="BPage.html">Show 2nd Tab of 'BPage.html'</a>
```

**BPage.html:**

```
<div id="tab1" style="display:none;">This is first tab content</div>
<div id="tab2" style="display:none;">This is Second tab content</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: page b will be shown seprately? or its like a step verification ?

Comment: will shown seperately.

Comment: OK. Now we know what do you want. What about showing us what you've done so far to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**APage.html:**

```
<a href="BPage.html#tab2">Show 2nd Tab of 'BPage.html'</a>
```

**BPage.html:**

```
<div id="tab1" style="dispaly:none;">This is first tab content</div>
<div id="tab2" style="dispaly:none;">This is Second tab content</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 document.getElementById(window.location.hash.substr(1)).style.display='block';
</script>
```

Comment: If I have tab inside tab and I want to open outer & inner  tab content both.This will not work.

Comment: for tab inside the tab you need to improve the JS to open all outer tabs:

Comment: Thnx Eduard Void for help.

Answer (score 0):

I have wrote this script which helped me.

```
var  lnk = window.location.hash;
    var cap= lnk.substr(1);
    var splt = cap.split('#');
    var str2 = splt[0];
    var str3 = splt[1];
    var str4 = splt[2];
    var str5 = splt[3];
    document.getElementById(str2).style.display='block'; /*BPage 1st Tabs box- 2nd Tab*/
    document.getElementById(str3).style.display='block'; /*BPage 2st Tabs Box*/
    document.getElementById(str4).style.display='none'; /* BPageHiding 1st Tabs box-Active tab#*/
    document.getElementById(str5).style.display='block'; /*BPage 2st Tabs Box- 1st active tab */
```

Comment: cannot you use var str2 = splt[0]; var str2 = splt[1]; etc. you are spliting string to array and then transforming it back to string. how did you get the values into substr method? what if the lenght of the anchors will differ?

Comment: for now anchor is static